# Error parsing Group_by function using dplyr in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, group-by, parameter-passing

I am working on a dataset containing many variables, with structures as characters

- A = character
- B_1 = character (some blank cells)
- B_2 = character (some blank cells)
- B_3 = character (some blank cells)
- B_4 = character (some blank cells)

I have created another variables by combining selected combinations of variables:

- `var1 <- "A|"B_"`
- `var2 <- "B_"`
- `var3 <- "A"`

My code below works fine until the group_by line and the pivot_longer line. I get errors that *var3 is not found (for group_by) or that using an external vector is ambiguous (for pivot_longer).*

However, when I run the function replacing {{var3}} with A, the script runs fine.

Please could you advise why {{var3}} does not currently work, and how I can fix this?

```
wrap_rtn <- function(var1, var2, var3) {
        df <- df %>% select(matches({{var1}})) %>%
                mutate_at(vars(starts_with({{var2}})),
                        funs(case_when(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", .) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))) %>%
                group_by({{var3}}) %>%
                summarize_all(funs(sum)) %>%
                pivot_longer(-{{var3}}, names_to = "Response", values_to = "Count")
```

Comment: First thing I notice is there are no closing quotes `"` in your `grepl` function. If that doesn't fix then try `get(var3)` instead of `{{var3}}` in your group by.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! get(var3) helped with the group_by error, but pivot_longer continues to throw errors, in part because the column named changed from A to get(var3). But this error prompted to think of another solution: I ended up adding code at the beginning to temporarily rename var3. I'll put my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

- var1 <- "wrapVar|"B_"
- var2 <- "B_"
- var3 <- "A"

```
wrap_rtn <- function(var1, var2, var3) {
        df_newname <- df %>% rename(wrapVar = {{var3}}
        df_newname <- df_newname %>% select(matches({{var1}})) %>%
                mutate_at(vars(starts_with({{var2}})),
                        funs(case_when(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", .) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))) %>%
                group_by(wrapVar) %>%
                summarize_all(funs(sum)) %>%
                pivot_longer(wrapVar}, names_to = "Response", values_to = "Count")
```